# SQL HAVING with both Aggregate and Conditional Statement

Tags: sql

I'm doing a few exercises on Study by Yourself and I came across this exercise 
on subgroups.

http://studybyyourself.com/seminar/sql/exercises/7-1/?lang=en

I got it wrong the first time (I put a WHERE statement with the author's names) and then I checked the solution, it was

```
SELECT *
FROM Author AS a
INNER JOIN Writing AS w ON w.Author_id = a.ID
INNER JOIN Book AS b ON b.ID = w.Book_id
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND a.Last_Name = 'Duncan' AND a.First_name = 'Andrew'
```

So I assume that it's alright to put conditional non-aggregate statements as long as they are paired with an aggregate in the HAVING statement, correct?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: It works, but I prefer `where` clause to do all the possible filtering. I prefer `having` do the summary filtering

Answer (score 2):

I would say move those `JOIN` conditions in a `WHERE` clause to apply the filter before grouping can happen and have only grouping or aggregation filter in `HAVING` clause since filter condition in `HAVING` clause applies to the aggregate result and are meant for that purpose

```
WHERE a.Last_Name = 'Duncan' AND a.First_name = 'Andrew'
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: If you're trying to LEARN SQL then this answer is clearly better - it's the correct way to go about solving this problem. A `HAVING` clause is like a `WHERE` statement for your aggregates. What you want to do is limit the query to only return rows for Andrew Duncan who only wrote one book.

This is a really terrible example both of database design and query logic. @Rahul did a much better job of helping to give you the correct way to accomplish this task. What the exercise was looking for was you understanding how to use a `HAVING` clause, but it used a poor example.

Answer (score 1):

Go find somewhere else to learn SQL.  That statement is incorrect, both syntactically and logically.

The correct solution would look more like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Author AS a INNER JOIN
     Writing AS w
     ON w.Author_id = a.ID INNER JOIN
     Book AS b
     ON b.ID = w.Book_id
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND
       MAX(a.Last_Name) = 'Duncan' AND
       MAX(a.First_name) = 'Andrew';
```

Columns from tables other than `b` should (properly speaking) also have aggregation functions.